# Column 'Rock' not found

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

При попытке запустить метод возникает ошибка:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'Rock' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1093)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5488)
    at DAO.MusicTypeDAO.getAll(MusicTypeDAO.java:108)
    at DAO.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Код метода:

```
public List<MusicType> getAll() {
        String requestMysql = "SELECT * FROM music_type;";
        List<MusicType> musicTypes = new ArrayList();
        PreparedStatement ps;
        try {
            ConnectionUtils.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);

            ps = ConnectionUtils.getConnection().prepareStatement(requestMysql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                MusicType musicType = new MusicType(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString(rs.getString("type_name")));
                musicTypes.add(musicType);
            }

            ConnectionUtils.getConnection().commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return musicTypes;
    }
```

ДБ:

```
CREATE database  if not exists `users_and_music` ;
USE users_and_music;

CREATE TABLE address (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country VARCHAR(256),
    street VARCHAR(256),
    zip INT
);
CREATE TABLE role (
     id  INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    role_name VARCHAR(256)
);
CREATE TABLE music_type (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type_name VARCHAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    role_id  INT NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    login VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    userpassword VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    age SMALLINT(3) DEFAULT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
        REFERENCES role (id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_music_type (
    user_id  INT  NOT NULL,
    music_type_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id,music_type_id ),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) 
        REFERENCES user (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (music_type_id)
        REFERENCES music_type (id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по стек-трейсу, исключение генерируется в этой строке:

```
MusicType musicType = new MusicType(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString(rs.getString("type_name")));
```

А именно из-за этого:

```
rs.getString(rs.getString("type_name"))
```

Здесь Вы получаете значение поля `type_name`, а затем пытаетесь получить значение поля с именем, которое вернуло `rs.getString("type_name")`, которого, очевидно, не существует.

В общем, попробуйте заменить эту строчку на вот эту:

```
MusicType musicType = new MusicType(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("type_name"));
```